# How to make search txt file and display value to input?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

My files on my directory are like this:

```
index.html
mobile.txt
adress.txt
country.txt
```

My HTML is like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="nameTxt" placeholder="Please Enter Your txt name hire"/>
    <input type="submit" id="findTxt" value="search"/> 
</form>
```

I want to display the contents of the search results:

```
<input type="text" id="diplayTxt" value=""/>
```

I tried this but it still fails:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").submit(function (event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var obj = document.getElementById("nameTxt").value;
    var dTxt = document.getElementById("diplayTxt");
    
    $.post("index.php", {obj:obj}, function(data){
      dTxt.value = data;
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$ft = $_POST['obj'];
$fh = fopen($ft.".txt", "r");

while ($line = fgets($fh)) 
{
  echo $line;
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: You will likely need to implement some sort of backend API which does the searching.

Comment: `Can i make it work`...yes absolutely. You'll need some PHP code which receives your AJAX request, searches the file, and returns the result.  Where are you stuck, exactly?

Comment: @ADyson , I have tried some php code, but it can't return the text. can you give a sample code?

Comment: You need [edit] the question to show what you've tried, and what it returns (whether error message or whatever else), then we can help you fix it. We don't just provide generic examples from nothing.

Comment: So, this "fails" in what way exactly? What debugging have you done? Any error messages? Or unexpected output?

Comment: N.B.  All this: `$fh = fopen($ft.".txt", "r");
while ($line = fgets($fh)) 
    {
    echo $line;
    }
fclose($fh);` could be simplified to just `echo file_get_contents($ft.".txt");`

Comment: @ADyson, I never imagined that before. thanks.. i will try it.